# How to Return Specific Data from WSDL GET function in VBA

Tags: vba

Basically what I'm trying to do is create an excel sheet that can query an item number and return it from a wsdl file on our web service, but no matter what code I try, it only returns the wsdl file itself.

```
strRequest = "http://webserver.com/WebServices/E1/Test.wsdl"
With objXmlHttp
.Open "POST", strRequest, False
.Open "GET", "http://webserver.com/WebServices/E1/Test.wsdl", False 
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic username:password"
End With
```

I've read that you can request information by adding ?wsdl=(query request) to the end of the GET url, but again, I only get wsdl. What is it I'm missing or not understanding? I've been googling for days and I can't find any helpful information

Comment: I am not sure if there is enough info above. For example, what is the specific data expected back? How are you parsing it from the response? What does the tech spec say about it? What does the response look like etc?

Comment: We expect a list of names that match our criteria at minimum to be returned in XML format. We will cover the parsing later, we just want the return for now. What do you mean by tech spec?